# How does your web development toolkit looks like?

Tags: language-agnostic

What are the web development tools you are using. Like firefox and firebug help me a lot with DOM. CVS for managing the code base. debugbar for IE. Can you suggest few of the open source tools that you have been using.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tools for faster, better web development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411954/tools-for-faster-better-web-development)

Comment: I read the post. Please let people add some interesting tools. I never saw mention of Selenium before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For code i use VIM, for testing phpunit, for functional testing Selenium RC. sometimes use firebug. Very seldom. Because all what i need tested by Selenium. Also always i have under my hands phpshell.
[Selenium-RC is the solution for tests that need more than simple browser actions and linear execution.](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html)

Comment: I didnt get Selenium what is it use for? Can u plz add a little.

Answer (score 2):

For Firefox, I find tamperdata very valuable in addition to firebug.  It lists exactly what URLs the browser is hitting along with the HTTP headers.

Comment: Does it provides something additional to Firefox?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  It's a firefox addon.

Comment: my bad. I mean does it provide something additional to firebug.