# What are the PHP-specific antipatterns that you know of?

Tags: php, anti-patterns

#### PHP as a Blunt Instrument

I hear PHP getting bashed around a lot lately. In quite a few projects, I have seen insane php code bases - so bad you really wonder if the person was on hallucinogenic drugs when they wrote the code. Sometimes, I wonder what the code would have been like if the initial developers had a bit more guidance as to what *not* to do.

However, I have also seen some very well organized PHP projects that were done in 100% OOP and were a pleasure to maintain, but they were not written by "php programmers."

I give all of our junior devs a link to [Java Anti-Patterns](http://www.odi.ch/prog/design/newbies.php). One of the nice things about that page is the Java-specific examples because there are many features of Java that lend themselves to common mistakes. I was hoping to find a similar list for php, but a google search did not reveal anything meaningful.

There are a few questions already out there for [what a developer should know when programming PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306497/what-should-every-php-programmer-know), but I wanted to focus on the negative.

What are the common things you have seen in PHP that should be avoided and what is a common solution to doing the same thing in a better way?

Some of the obvious examples to me that I think will be mentioned but aren't PHP specific:

- Don't concatenate SQL. Use prepare statements or proper escaping.
- Don't blindly embed PHP into HTML - use templating/MVC.
- Don't blindly post raw unfiltered user input - scrub it for XSS attacks.
- Don't manually try to parse all of your POSTs and GETs - use a web framework.

Here would be some examples that I would consider PHP specific:

- Don't have too many layers of file include/require linking and try to avoid conditional linking. Rather, have a sane naming convention and be consistent with your organization.
- Don't use PHPs raw database API unless you can help it, instead use a database framework like [ADODB](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/) instead.
- Don't overuse PHP's dynamic typing by setting the variable to a string in one place and a boolean somewhere else, then expecting the boolean tests to make sense.

So, what are your favorite PHP *don'ts* and how do you do it right?

Comment: Woudln't this be better as a community wiki?

Answer (score 16):

I disagree with this one:

- Don't blindly embed PHP into HTML - use templating/MVC.

**PHP is a templating language**. While I agree with the concept of implementing MVC, I don't see why there should be a requirement to implement a yet another DSL around producing web output.

Comment: +1 I agree. If a page is a pretty complex, you should use mvc, but it's simple enough mvc for page's design can be overkill especially if you are using your custom framework (the next person who will work on your code probably will damn you :D)

Comment: I like the way CodeIgniter does it - but in the framework it essentially becomes the view. So what do you do when you need an internationalized version of your page with different fonts, layout and marketing content for your new market when you don't have interchangeable views?

Comment: Don't you just love it how there's a boat load of templating languages out there, implemented in PHP?

Comment: By the same logic, if PHP is a "templating language," then I should scoff at you for using it to write business logic. Using templates allows you to a) be more expressive with less verbosity and b) offer a secure way for untrusted users to create content. Of course plain PHP can often be used directly as the template layer (and usually is the best option), but that doesn't make it the end-all.

Comment: PHP WAS A TEMPLATING LANGUAGE!

Comment: why bother giving your application the task of parsing a template file every request, when PHP html code islands work perfectly fine...

Comment: PHP started off as a templating language, it's more than that now... People also used to smoke in Airplanes, but now we know better than to do that...

Answer (score 9):

Adding closing "?>" tags to the end of php files can lead to accidentally pushing white-spaces to the output buffer.  The PHP interpreter will automatically add closing tags to files, and doing it manually is somewhat of an anti-pattern.

Comment: From the PHP documentation: "If a file is pure PHP code, it is preferable to omit the PHP closing tag at the end of the file."  See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Answer (score 5):

1. Never EVER use a `$_GET` or `$_POST` without checking it and cleaning it up.
2. Read about how to set up the `php.ini` right.
3. Never put variables into raw SQL.
4. If you use frameworks, use the ones with less dependencies.
5. Stop over-generalization.
6. Distribute your code on the php files. In most cases there is no real need to put everything into one `index.php`.
7. Reduce complexity before writing code.
8. Respect the fact that it is a web application. (Try to be [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer).) It's not a desktop application. So stop putting everything into `$_SESSION`.
9. At least one comment line for every 10 lines of code. You WILL read that after a year. I promise!
10. Code [like a girl](http://headrush.typepad.com/creating_passionate_users/2006/03/code_like_a_gir.html) - make it nice to read.

Comment: Can't agree with 9. Of course you will read that after a year but code should be selfcomenting enough to understand it. Comments are getting old much faster than code. It's easier to maintain code naming conventions than keeping in mind to update comments all the time.

Answer (score 5):

My current pet peeve is inconsistent-return-type for query-functions. This is when you call a function to execute a query, and it returns

1. NULL or FALSE or something similar when no match is found
2. The matching object/value when a single match is found
3. array of matching objects/values when more than one match was found

which forces you to check the return types and deal with each case specifically. It would be much better to simply always return an array with 0, 1 or n elements.

Answer (score 2):

One of my favourite DON'Ts would have to be:

```
$query = 'select * from users where username = ' . $_POST['username'];
```

Can it get much scarier than that?

Comment: yes it can, $_REQUEST['username']...

Comment: $query='SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=\''.$_COOKIE['username'].'\' AND password=\''.$_COOKIE['password'].'\'';
The same error, but nobody suspects anything wrong in $_COOKIE.

Comment: @roe, $_REQUEST is scarier! I was going for the idea of directly using super-globals in queries as opposed to $_POST specifically, should have made that clear.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to include a favourite don't it has to be the one posted by karim79:

```
$query = 'select * from users where username = ' . $_POST['username'];
```

Many developers in PHP keep stuck in structured age. PHP supports classes and objects since a while ago, I just don't get why people keep hard coding PHP into html, without templates or nothing at all.

I believe that developers from other languages, like .NET or Java have earned the right to criticize the language if so many developers keep programming like that. PHP is a very great language, very flexible, still a little junior but is growing, but many just don't get it, all they want is to solve by making the old classic copy & paste.

Answer (score 0):

- use SPL
- use PDO instead of using mysql_query or pg_query or others
- always use the filter extension on user input